# Agilizar consulta SQL com DataTables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, jquery-datatables, tabela-banco-de-dados

A consulta abaixo retorna uma `DataTables` com aproximadamente 400 itens do banco de dados `Mysql`. A dificuldade consiste em retornar estes valores de forma mais rápida. Atualmente leva em média 70 segundos para exibir por completo a lista. É um número baixo de itens mesmo assim há uma grande demora. Há possibilidade de melhorar o desempenho através do `SELECT`?

```
SELECT 
   p.*,
   pc.*,
   u.name as autor, u.surname
FROM 
    `product` p
INNER JOIN
    `product_config` pc ON p.id = pc.id_product
LEFT JOIN
    `users` u ON u.id = p.idAutor
ORDER BY 
    p.id DESC
```

Comment: Você precisa mesmo selecionar tudo (*) em duas tabelas? Tem certeza que o gargalo é a query? Se você executar o select 'por fora' ele também demora? Como são os índices nessa tabela?

Comment: @Genos fiz a seleção apenas dos campos úteis na montagem da Datatables e realmente não teve muita alteração no carregamento. Uma das colunas exibia a imagem do produto, retirei está informação e o desempenho mudou drasticamente. Creio que tenha relação com o carregamento das imagens na DataTables, já que ela aguarda todos os elementos serem carregados.

Comment: @Dagobe você chegou a usar a funcionalidade de server-side processing do plugin?

Comment: @Cesar não. O que eu fiz foi retirar uma imagem do produto que carregava numa das colunas.